# How can I force the blocksize when using gdal_rasterize?

Tags: gdal-rasterize

I am rasterizing a shapefile of continents. I use the following command:

```
gdal_rasterize -burn 1  -ts 1440000 560000 -te -180 -60 180 80 -ot Byte -co COMPRESS=PACKBITS -co NUM_THREADS=ALL_CPUS -co BLOCKXSIZE=256 -co BLOCKYSIZE=256 -co PREDICTOR=2 continent.shp continents.tif
```

You can see I specify the blocksize to be 256 x 256. Yet when I check the blocksize:

```
blah = gdal.Open(continents.tif)
blah.GetRasterBand(1).GetBlockSize()

Out[74]: [1440000, 256]
```

gdal_rasterize is overwriting my BLOCKXSIZE specification and instead using the number of columns. Is there any way to force the 256x256 blocksize?

I understand that larger x-blocksizes are more I/O efficient generally, but not for my specific application.

Comment: Do you have to force tiling for the TIFF Format with -co "TILED=YES"?

Comment: I don't want to tile the raster--I want one TIFF file with 256x256 blocksize. I believe that tiling outputs many smaller individual tiff files.

Comment: No, TILED defines how the Bytes are organized inside the TIFF file. It does not outputs smaller individual tiff files. By default stripped TIFF files are created. But you want a tiled TIFF, since you specified the blocksize 256x256

Comment: If you do not set tiled=yes you will get a striped tiff and only blockysize has any effect. Just what you experienced. You do want to get a tiled tiff http://www.gdal.org/frmt_gtiff.html.

Comment: Ah, OK. The gdal TIFF options says "TILED=YES: By default stripped TIFF files are created. This option can be used to force creation of tiled TIFF files." I assumed that "stripped TIFF files" referred to the same output as gdal_retile. If @Saleika makes an answer I will accept.

Comment: That should say "I assumed that "*tiled* TIFF files" referred to the same output as gdal_retile."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To force the 256x256 blocksize you have to add the `-co "TILED=YES"` Option

```
gdal_rasterize -burn 1  -ts 1440000 560000 -te -180 -60 180 80 -ot Byte -co COMPRESS=PACKBITS -co NUM_THREADS=ALL_CPUS -co "TILED=YES" -co BLOCKXSIZE=256 -co BLOCKYSIZE=256 -co PREDICTOR=2 continent.shp continents.tif
```